# App Store version gets the last expo build version, even I didn't released it

Tags: react-native, expo

I've faced a weird behaviour in my expo app.

My steps:

- I created a new version (1.0.8) using expo build:ios
- The current version release in App Store is 1.0.6
- I downloaded and install it in my iPhone
- So, I got the 1.0.8 version, but this version is only in TestFlight, it wasn't released yet.

How is it possible?

Comment: `expo build` automatically runs `expo publish` and then builds the app based on that published bundle. you can use release channels for new builds to avoid this. expo's new build service, EAS Build, also does not have this behavior.

Comment: So @brentvatne, 'eas build --platform ios' command won't publish directly?

Comment: right. the source code present at build time will be bundled but it will not be published as an update.